# CSS filter application order

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-filters

It appears that CSS filters do not following the same rules as other CSS properties, including overriding and order of application.

Firstly, they can only be overlapped, not overridden (replaced), by filters in descendant elements.  Secondly, changing CSS rule specificity does not seem to change the order of application of these filters.  This is the problem I'm dealing with now.

As seen in this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/qozehi/7/edit?html,css,output), the brightness filter is being applied before the invert filter, resulting in the opposite effect of what I need.  I need the invert filter to be applied first to an ancestor, and the brightness filter to be applied afterwards to a specific descendant.

The only solution I've come up with involves using :not() to exclude the descendant from the ancestor filter, enabling me to apply a separate (non-overlapping) filter to the descendant.  This, however, resulted in very poor performance in our single page application (single, large DOM).

Any ideas on how to apply the invert filter first in this situation, or another solution?

*Please note that I need filters to do the work, rather than manually applying specific colors to the descendant element, because I'm actually filtering a colorful image.  I used text in the JS Bin for simplicity.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    }
    .normal {
      background: white;
    }
    .brighter {
      background: white;
      -webkit-filter: brightness(200%);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="normal">normal night mode text</div>
  <div class="brighter">brighter night mode text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Overriding and order of application are completely irrelevant when you're talking about different elements altogether (in this case, an ancestor vs a descendant). This is true for any CSS property, including filter.

Comment: @BoltClock By override I mean replace a CSS property, inherited from an ancestor, in a descendant.  I can do this with other CSS properties, but not with filters.  By order of application I mean brightness being applied after invert.  Using these definitions they are very relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of the things you mention is the real issue. You can easily override filters (as seen when browser prefixes are included) and use specificity to help do so if you wish.

The real problem is that the invert filter is being applied on the parent, which includes all of the children. This is a problem because the parent waits for the children to be calculated (not painted) before applying any filters. This is how it's supposed to work (and how other visual effects like `clip-path` and `transform` function).

As such, you will need to work around this by either applying the invert filter to all elements except the one you don't want it to apply to or somehow move the element outside of the parent context with the invert filter.

It's possible to apply multiple filters using the format `filter: invert(100%) brightness(200%);`. The order of application goes from left to right, as is standard in CSS.

Comment: In other words, the children are calculated first, and the result is that the brightness filter is applied before the invert filter, which is what I mentioned.  By override I mean replace a CSS property, inherited from an ancestor, in a descendant. I can do this with other CSS properties, but not with filters.

Comment: @fearlessbryan Exactly. There is no other answer